# SharePoint: GetListItemChangesSinceToken vs GetListItemChangesWithKnowledge?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

What *is* the difference between [`GetListItemChangesSinceToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistitemchangessincetoken.aspx) and [`GetListItemChangesWithKnowledge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistitemchangeswithknowledge.aspx)?

Here is the *awesome* summary documentation, and about all that is said on the matter:

> **GetListItemChangesSinceToken:** Returns changes made to the list since the date and time specified in the [change] token.
>
> **GetListItemChangesWithKnowledge:** Returns all of the list items that meet specified criteria and that have changed since the date-time specified in the knowledge parameter for the specified list.

One takes a "change token" and the other takes "knowledge". However, I have not been able to find *any* documentation (or rationale) as to what advantage one has over the other, why they both exist, how they are fundamentally different, or which one is appropriate to use in protocol clients.

These SOAP services are formally defined in the [[MS-LISTSWS]: Lists Web Service Protocol Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/8/858F2155-D48D-4C68-9205-29460FD7698F/%5BMS-LISTSWS%5D.pdf) protocol, but they seem identical, excepting the token they expect and emit. (Perhaps it is just the number of undocumented bugs?)

While `GetListItemChangesWithKnowledge` *does* have an additional `syncScope` parameter, MS-LISTWS says:

> [syncScope] MUST be null or empty ... [syncScope] is reserved and MUST be ingored

Any input -- *especially* first-hand knowledge -- is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably right about the number of bugs being the difference...

Here is what I could find about both methods:

**`GetListItemChangesWithKnowledge`** ([different MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd924166.aspx))

- [SharePoint 2010: Lists.GetListItemChangesWithKnowledge Method](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-2010-ListsGetListItemChangesWithKnowledge-Method.aspx) suggests that this method was introduced with SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Workspace synchronization - I couldn't verify this though
- The important bit is *"returns all of the list items that meet specified criteria and that have changed **since the date-time specified** in the knowledge parameter for the specified list"*
- Diving further in: The `knowledge` element contains "Microsoft Sync Framework knowledge data structure" (MSDN), which for example is explained here ([Microsoft Sync Framework, Part 2: Sync Metadata](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreimaksimenka/archive/2007/11/09/microsoft-sync-framework-part-2-sync-metadata.aspx)).

**`GetListItemChangesSinceToken`** ([different MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff831919%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

- *Should* be used instead of `GetListItemChanges` according to MSDN (see link above). I'm assuming it should be used because the `Change` element further specifies the list item to get, as it says *"If Nothing is passed, all items in the list are returned."*
- The `changeToken` actually contains something from the [Change Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417456.aspx), which in turn has information about Adds, Deletes, Renames etc. --> This is useful if you have in-depth synchronization in your application
- On [Synchronizing with Windows SharePoint Services, Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2008/01/21/synchronizing-with-windows-sharepoint-services-part-1.aspx) the snychronization is explained, including a bit information on the `changeToken`.

---

**Summary:** It looks to me that the ...WithKnowledge method is a bit more complex as it is using the Microsoft Sync's Framework query syntax which includes a time constraint for changes. The ...SinceToken method only queries for all changes with specified action (e.g. Delete) without time constraint.
Ask yourself: Do you really want to implement such complicated methods with lacking documentation which are subject to change? I would suggest doing two things: Analyze (e.g. via Fiddler) the traffic Microsoft Workspace 2010 is generating (also check Word/Outlook). What methods is is using? Could you implement something similar? Isn't `GetListItemChanges` enough for most applications?

Comment: Thanks for your input. We are currently using `..ChangeToken`, and it works well-enough. `GetListItems`, while simpler, just doesn't scale nice for continuous synchronization. `..ChangeToken` at least has a *largely undocumented* (grr!) feature where it actually provides a change-delta based on the *Query Filter*; I have not tested this with `..WithKnowledge`, but *if/how it works might differ*. The only semi tip-off of such feature is the very brief mention to the Change Log (grr!) as pointed out. Since I am not using the Sync framework, and the code is in place, `..ChangeToken` it is for me!

Comment: Very interesting! Out of curiosity: What are you actually synching? Some documents from some doc-lib to some local forms application?

Comment: Just normal SharePoint lists -- the basic (e.g. Task) fields and any user defined columns. Our functional requirements call for 10k items (after the filter) and it's designed for corporate deployment (tens of thousands of users). Attached documents as well, but those are a separate issue. Think of normal SharePoint STSSYNC integration ... on lots of caffeine. You are very correct though: I should definitely setup a fiddler2/wireshark capture on the STSSYNC.